# IBM Integration Bus on AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ibm-integration-bus

Can IBM Integration Bus((and /or Websphere message Broker) be implemeted on AWS ? Can my on-premise ESB be migrated to AWS Cloud ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

AWS EC2 allows importing VMs into an AMI then you can start an EC2 instance using that image. If you are new to AWS you can check the link below
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/
However, you should be careful about IIB license and how many machines you can install it on before regesting the AMI in a launch configuration and create an autoscaling group and set a scaling policy that can start instances more that what you purchased.

Answer (score 1):

That's very much possible. There are several possible approaches.

**1. IIB on EC2**

Installing and configuring IIB on an EC2 instance is very much similar to doing the same in on-premise servers. Only difference is that the physical server is in AWS Cloud. While this approach gives you maximum flexibility to design your architecture any way, it does not take advantage of the basic features of the cloud.

**2. Quick Start**

IIB is available for deployment under AWS Quick Start. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2018/01/16/quickstart-deployment-ibm-integration-bus-aws-cloud/). This helps you get started quickly by setting up the entire environment in a few clicks. But, if you're planning to migrate your existing architecture to AWS, this may not suit you as the architecture is pre-defined with limited options for customization.

**3. IIB on Containers**

ACE 11 provides better support for containerization. You can read more about running IIB 10 on containers [here](https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2015/06/22/running-ibm-integration-bus-v10-docker-container/) and ACE 11 on containers [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTTDS_11.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bz91300_.html). After this, the containers can be deployed into fully managed containers such as AWS Elastic Container Service or your own container configuration such as Docker on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, AWS provides the IAAS and you just install whatever you want inside. Make sure you open ports, use specific credentials for the instalation (dont use admin) and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

IBM also provides docker images of integration bus v10 and APP Connect Enterprise v11. This is true for all their integration tools, MQ, API Management and more.

Not restricted to AWS.